# VSCodeでtextlintが正常に動作しない

Tags: vscode

現在.rstファイルにてナレッジ執筆業務をしており、文書校正を自動化したくtextlintおよび [textlint-plugin-rst](https://github.com/shiguredo/textlint-plugin-rst) というプラグインを実装しました。

テスト用にtest.rstというファイルを作成し、
「テストかもしれません」とだけ入力しターミナルにてtextlint test.rstを実行すると
①【  1:4   error  弱い表現: "かも" が使われています。  ja-technical-writing/ja-no-weak-phrase
1:10  error  文末が"。"で終わっていません。       ja-technical-writing/ja-no-mixed-period】
というエラーが出力されることを確認できました。

ここに「設定することができます」という行を追加したところ、
②【  1:1  ✓ error  【dict2】 "することができます"は冗長な表現です。"することが"を省き簡潔な表現にすると文章が明瞭になります。
解説: https://github.com/textlint-ja/textlint-rule-ja-no-redundant-expression#dict2  ja-technical-writing/ja-no-redundant-expression】
というエラーのみが出力され、
①のエラーが出力されなくなってしまう事象が発生しています。

.mdファイルでは正常なエラー出力がされているので、ルール設定等が悪いわけではないと思うのですが、
知識不足のため原因の究明ができず、お手上げ状態です。

.rstファイルに対して正常に校正チェックが入るよう、どなたかご教示いただけますと幸いです。

以下に設定ファイルの情報を記載します。

.textlintrc.json

```js
{
  "plugins": {
    "rst":true
    },
  "filters": {},
  "rules": {
    "preset-ja-technical-writing": true
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "npx textlint --plugin rst source/*rst"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "textlint": "^13.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "textlint-plugin-rst": "github:shiguredo/textlint-plugin-rst#shiguredo",
    "textlint-rule-preset-ja-technical-writing": "^7.0.0"
  }
}
```

①の段階のtest.rstは

```
1　テストかもしれません
```

②の段階のtest.rstは

```
1　テストかもしれません
2　設定することができます
```

としていました。

Comment: 近い環境を持っているのでライブラリ周りを合わせて試してみましたが、①のエラーが全て消えるまでの再現ができませんでした。（1:4は変わらず出力される）

可能であれば、①の時点と②の時点のtest.rstも掲載してもらえますか。

Comment: コメントいただきましたところ、確認が遅くなり申し訳ございません。
①の段階のtest.rstは
```
1　テストかもしれません
```
②の段階のtest.rstは
```
1　テストかもしれません
2　設定することができます
```
としていました。

Comment: 私もこの問題は再現しませんでした。
2行目を追加しても、1行目の「かも」のエラーは消えません。
`textlint` コマンドの出力をそのまま貼り付けていただくと、何か手掛りが有るかも知れません。
ところで、VSCodeはこの質問にどのように関わっていますか？

Comment: rstファイルの記載形式がよくなく、1行空白を入れたところ上記コードのままで正常に動作することを確認しました。
ご回答ありがとうございました。